# Is board ASROCK Z690 PG Riptide Socket LGA1700 compatible with ubuntu server 22.04.3 LTS

Tags: drivers, server, lts, compatibility

I am currently building a file server for a small office on Linux and I would like to know if this board is compatible:     ASRock Z690 PG Riptide ATX LGA1700 Motherboard

The full build is here

https://pcpartpicker.com/list/h7HdDZ

Is there a list with boards compatible with ubuntu lts?
Any advice will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Will my device work with Ubuntu?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/986878/will-my-device-work-with-ubuntu)